# Whirlpool Dryer 110.67902790 - Screws on the Back Panel (was replacing Thermal Fuse)

Tags: screws, dryer

Dryer model: Whirlpool 110.67902790 (from like 2005).

I removed the screws on the back of my dryer to attempt to get to the thermal fuse. After doing so, I realized the back of this model is basically welded on... and you get to the fuse from the front, which I did successfully.

[image: Picture of the back]

As I try to put the screws back in REAR of the dryer, I cannot get the 3 circled in red to line up and go back in. The top few (circled in green) went back in fine.

Do these three screws matter?
They seem like they only go metal to metal in holding the back panel on flush. Or was it holding a component that dropped?

Comment: they were holding something on the inside and now no longer do so

Answer (score 1):

Those screws support the rear bulkhead which hold a drum roller and also supports the heat duct. While they are not the only screws holding the pieces in place, they are needed. You need to get under the drum from the front and line the inside parts up. It'll be easier with two people, one to line up and one to screw in the parts.

Comment: Similar to what Jack said - that back panel actually makes up part of the structure for the dryer.  Besides acting as a support for the drum, it also serves to stiffen up the entire metal box.  So all 7 screws are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Can this be done without taking the drum out?  Just one person lifting it up and one person in the back to get the screw(s) in when it's lined up?

Comment: @Mac  You should be able to, possibly lifting up with a 2x4  or just pressing in with one.